# Адаптивный(bootstrap) select2

Tags: html, bootstrap, select2

Хочу сделать, чтобы кастомный select2 адаптировался под изменение окна, как инпуты под бутстраповским col-sm-5.При постепенном изменении размера он не уменьшается постепенно(скрин1)[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Но под формат телефонов он трансформируется.(скрин2)
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Как это исправить? Вот код:

```
   <div class="col-sm-5">
     <select class="form-control" id="id8" name = "id8">
<option  disabled>Выберите тип участника</option>
<option selected value="участник информационного обмена</option>
#другие варианты
</select>
</div>

 .select2-container {
  width: 740px !important;
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  .select2-container {
    width: 100% !important;
      position: relative !important;
  }
}
.select2-dropdown {
  background-color: white;
  border: 1px solid #aaa;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  left: -100000px;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: 1051;
   }
.select2-container .select2-selection--single {
  height: 40px !important;
}
.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__rendered {
  line-height: 40px !important;
}
.select2-container--default .select2-selection--single .select2-selection__arrow {
  height: 40px !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вручную прописал медиа запросы на каждые 100px